# bitcoin cgminer setup arch

Tags: linux, bitcoin, archlinux

Trying to set up bitcoin miner on arch linux AMD 64bit.
I get this error, with cgminer on arch linux:

```
[2013-03-20 19:52:41] Started cgminer 2.11.3
[2013-03-20 19:52:41] Error -1001: clGetPlatformsIDs failed (no OpenCL SDK installed?)
[2013-03-20 19:52:41] clDevicesNum returned error, no GPUs usa
```

I was trying to resolve dependencies, but need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either:

- You haven't installed the proprietary drivers from AMD, or
- You haven't installed AMD's APP SDK - http://developer.amd.com/tools/heterogeneous-computing/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/

You will find cgmier's list of dependencies and other important things on its README page.